# Primary Key and Unique Index -- sql scripts generated by SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When export sql scripts by SQL Developer there are multiple options available, but either way there have to generate a `UNIQUE INDEX` on primary key like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SYS_C0018099" ON "TRANSACTION" ("ID")
```

and add `PRIMARY KEY` to the same table and same column

```
ALTER TABLE "TRANSACTION" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
```

So the question is: does it looks like kind of redundancy? I thought creating a primary key on a column should by default create an unique index on that column too? So why the first command is necessary?

And this may cause data redundancy?

I am on Oracle 11g so please share any ideas about why it should look like above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: reading this might help you http://viralpatel.net/blogs/understanding-primary-keypk-constraint-in-oracle/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no redundancy - or only a little bit :)

The second command will use the index available if exists. Otherwise(if first DDL does not exists) will create an index.

The split into two commands is useful when you had given a proper name to the index and want to keep it.

**UPDATE**: The link indicated by Thomas Haratyk is a must read, I really like it: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/understanding-primary-keypk-constraint-in-oracle/

**UPDATE2**: a_horse_with_no_name is right, it can be done in a single statement like:

```
alter table TRANSACTION
add CONSTRAINT pk_test PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

So, it will keep the name(won't create a sysblalbla object name) and if you use the 'USING INDEX' keyword you can specify index atributes, for example storage atributes.

But again, you will not have any problems with those two statements, only an index is created.

Probably SQL Developer prefer to get a ddl per object and there might be cases when it's better its way.

Comment: Thanks for the intel. @a_horse_with_no_name could you please give an single statement as a formal combination of the two `with an index name`? I mean, can we specify an index name within `ALTER TABLE` command when creating primary key? Thanks

Comment: @Dreamer: `alter table foo add constraint pk_foo primary key (id)` will create a constraint named `PK_FOO` and an index with the same name. You can define the index separately if you want: `alter table foo add constraint pk_foo primary key (id) using index (create index pk_index_for_foo on foo(id));`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thumbs up for the wonderful comment! Thank you a_horse_with_no_name ;)